# Impossible to pass string through activities at the beginning

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to pass a string from an activity to another activity.
I need this string to send an Http request with a specific key (the string) as a header.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StatusActivity.class).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
intent.putExtra("token", token);
startActivity(intent);
```

I try to get the value in the other activity:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        //

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        token = intent.getExtras().getString("token");
        adapter = new ObjAdapter(getActivity() ,new ArrayList<Post>());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

But the problem is that I initialize an ArrayAdapter inside the method onCreate, because I want the data to be present at the beginning of the activity. It seems that the token is null and cannot be found.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new StatusFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    FeedAsync task = new FeedAsync();
    task.execute();
}
```

How can I get the string token at the beginning of the activity?
I need the string token to execute the AsyncTask.

Comment: It seems that you "try to get the value" in a fragment attached to (perhaps) another activity. Move the retrieving snippet from the `onCreateView` method to `onActivityCreated` or somewhere where you have the intent of the parent activity for sure. You can also pass it to the Fragment's constructor, and save there in its arguments for later processing.

Comment: Place your token fetching code inside `StatusActivity` `onCreate()´ method, instead. Make sure you are sending some value as token in the FirstActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "most beginning" place in `Activity` is `onCreate` method after calling of `super` method. There is no earliest place where you could get `Intent` data.

Comment: How can I execute my AsyncTask with the token at the begining of the activity in this case?

Comment: @rusol what do you mean `how`? As any other `AsyncTask`. Your code is ok. I suppose you just need to create your adapter after finishing of `AsyncTask`.